# Logic App - initialize variable from JSON Content

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I am new to Logic APP and was wondering how to parse Json attributes . In other words 
passing the below Jason to a queue (the values will change as we send different Json to the queue)

```
[ 
  {
     "name":"test",
     "country":"USA" 

  } 
]
```

I am trying to get name & country

Here are the steps I took
[image]

then I added JSON parse Action ( not sure if this is the right action)
[image]
[image]

then ( I am just trying to get the attributes name & country)

[image]

Then I get error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this requirement, please refer to the steps I provided below:

**1.** I initialize a variable named "myData" first to simulate your json data.
[image]

**2.** To get the value of the `name` and `country`, we just do as below:
[image]
The expressions for `name` and `country` are:

```
variables('myData')[0]?['name']
variables('myData')[0]?['country']
```

As your logic app starts with the "When a message is received in a queue(peek-lock)" trigger, it seems your json data comes from the trigger. So you need to change the expression to something like:

```
triggerBody()[0]?['name']
```

If your json data doesn't come from the trigger(service bus message), please let me know and provide more details, or you can click "Peek code" to see its expression and then modify your expression in initialize variable action.

**Update:**

It seems we can not parse the "content" from the trigger directly, you can initialize a variable to store the "content" from the queue trigger and use "Parse JSON" action to parse this "content" variable.
[image]

Comment: My logic app starts with When a message is received in a queue(peek-lock)" trigger..So I used triggerBody()[0]?['name'] but I get error  'triggerBody()[0]?['name']' cannot be evaluated because property '0' cannot be selected...if I use variables('myData')[0]?['name'] it works but the value is always the same

Comment: updated my code above, tried another way but still getting an error

Comment: @rgoal Why did you put the "Content" from the trigger to the "Content" box of the "Parse JSON" action ? I'm not sure what you want to parse json, but it seems you should put the "body" from the trigger to the "Content" box of the "Parse JSON" action.

Comment: I am just trying to get the attributes our of the json line my above code...not sure how to   put the "body" from the trigger to the "Content" box of the "Parse JSON" action.

Comment: also when I used your above code I get an error using triggerBody()[0]?['name']' cannot be evaluated because property '0' cannot be selected.

Comment: @rgoal I'm not sure which item you should set in the "content" box of "Parse JSON" because I don't know where your json data come from. I mean you need to put your json data in the "content" box of "Parse JSON". If your json data come from the trigger body, then put the trigger body in "content" box. If it comes from anything else, then put it in the "content" box of "Parse JSON".

Comment: I updated my code above in an effort to make it more clear...I am passing (json) the values to a queue then reading the values from queue..since I am new to this not sure what do you mean by trigger body in the content ...also not sure if parse jason is the right step

Comment: Hi @rgoal The screenshots you provided show that the "content" from the trigger is not a json format. You can initialize a variable named "content" and set the value as the "content" from the trigger and then use "Parse JSON" parse this "content" variable but not parse the "content" from the trigger. Please refer to the "Update" in my answer.